# xml node name validation

Tags: xml, regex, context-free-grammar

I want to create regex which will validate xml node name. I have found grammar for names, but I don't know what some parts of it means. http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/07/25/namingparts.html

```
[4] NameChar ::= Letter | Digit | '.' | '-' | '_' | ':' | CombiningChar | Extender
[5] Name ::= (Letter | '_' | ':') (NameChar)*
```

What does CombiningChar and Extender mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your spec I think this should do the trick:

```
(\w|_|:)(\w|\d|\.|-|_|:)*
```

That's without CombiningChar and Extender. In the [official spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) you can find what exactly is meant with CombiningChar and Extender (Ctrl+F for these on that page), you'd however have to translate the unicode codes.